# Grail Junit controller test: request.withformat

Tags: grails, junit

I've been tasked with writing a (Grails) Junit integration for this section of controller code - and I've never seen anything like it before.  This is a project for creating and populating a list of faq's; whereby an faq consists of category, question, and answer fields. The section of the method in question I'd like to test is as follows:

```
static allowedMethods = [index: 'GET', show: 'GET', create: 'GET', edit: 'GET', save: 'POST', update: 'PUT', faq:'GET', delete:'DELETE']

... more stuff

    @Transactional
    def save(Faq faqInstance) {
... other stuff....

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'faq.label', default: 'FAQ'), faqInstance.id])
                redirect faqInstance
            }
            '*' { respond faqInstance, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    }
```

I'm still learning this stuff, so this actually might be easier that my knowledge allows for.  :)  I've started to mock out a Junit test that inputs a very generic faq, but I'm not sure what it's supposed to return or how else to proceed....

```
void "test save with request of form"(){
    def cont = new FaqController()
    cont.request.method = 'POST'
    cont.params.category = 'General'
    cont.params.question = "This is a question"
    cont.params.answer = "This is an answer"
    cont.save()
    //what to return?   
}
```

Thanks for your help, and forgive my ignorance if I'm overlooking something obvious. :)

-ryan

Comment: see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers to learn about testing Controllers (replace latest in the url with your grails version if you don't use 2.4). It also mentions withFormat.

Comment: I've already read through that portion and it doesn't address my needs.  I need to find an example of Integration Testing in the Junit style that addresses withFormat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check `controller.response`, something like this:

```
void testControllerRespondsWithJson () {
    def controller = new FooController()
    controller.request.method = 'POST'
    controller.params.category = 'General'
    controller.params.question = "This is a question"
    controller.params.answer = "This is an answer"
    controller.response.format = 'json'

    controller.save ()

    def json = controller.response.json
    assert controller.response.status == HttpServletResponse.SC_CREATED
    assert json.category == controller.params.category
    // ...
}
```

`controller.response.text` is the "standard" result, a `String`. In case of a json result it is easier to parse it into a json object and check that.